# Does there exist a function in $f \in L^\infty (\mathbb{R})$ such that $\operatorname{dist} (f, BC(\mathbb{R})) > 0$?

Tags: real-analysis

In the title $BC (\mathbb{R})$ refers to the bounded continuous functions on $\mathbb{R}$.

Clearly $f$ must be discontinuous, and I also believe that $f$ should at least be discontinuous on a set of positive measure. An idea I had which I couldn't flesh out was that if we use some sort of indicator function which varies between $0$ and $1$ on some sets of $\mathbb{R}$ such that the "best possible" approximation in the sense of the $L^\infty$ norm would be the constant function $g(x) = \frac{1}{2}$.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried to prove that such function does not exist?

Comment: No I have not, I will give it a try, but I strongly believe such a function exists.

Comment: $BC(\Bbb R)$ is a closed subspace of $L^\infty$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich ...and since $BC (\mathbb{R})$ is a proper subset of $L^\infty (\mathbb{R})$ then there must exist some $f$ in the complement of $BC (\mathbb{R})$ such that $d(f, BC (\mathbb{R})) > 0$ since otherwise it would be in the closure of it, which would imply in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For fun, a specific example: Let $f= \chi_{[0,\infty)}.$ Suppose $g\in BC$ and $\|f-g\|_\infty <1/2.$ Then $\sup_{[0,\infty)} |f-g| < 1/2.$ Therefore $g>1/2$ on $[0,\infty).$ Similarly, $g<1/2$ on $(-\infty,0).$ But no continuous function can satisfy both inequalities, by the intermediate value theorem. This is a contradiction, so we have $\|f-g\|_\infty \ge 1/2.$ Thus $d(f,BC) \ge 1/2.$ (And in fact $d(f,BC) = 1/2,$ since the constant fuction $1/2$ belongs to $BC,$ and $d(f,1/2) = 1/2.$)

Comment: The comment by David C. Ullrich reduced the problem to an elementary one of topology, but I will give you the answer for a nice construction! Thank you!